# Drop annotation on virtual map swift3

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

please help me out.

First time working on a project, with iBeacon involved, which creating *Virtual map* of inside of a store.

I know how to drop pins, with a MapKit, but how can i do it, if i only have CGPoints on View ? 
I managed how to drip UIImage(with pin image), on a view. But when i rotate or pinch, it's not stay on that coordinates that i dropped.
Here's a code :

```
import UIKit



class MapViewController: UIViewController{


    private var scaleView: CGFloat = 1
    private var rotateView: CGFloat = 0
    private var anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    private let gestureRecognizerDelegate = GestureRecognizerDelegate()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MapView!
    @IBOutlet var pinchGestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet var rotateGestureRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet weak var pin: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if !cartIsEmpty {
            cartBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "haveitem"), for: .normal)

        } else {
            cartBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "2772"), for: .normal)

        }
        cartBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openCart), for: .touchUpInside)
        let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cartBtn)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item1
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cartBtn.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(openCart), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            ApplicationManager.sharedInstance.onApplicationStart()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onOrientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
        self.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = gestureRecognizerDelegate
        self.pinchGestureRecognizer.delegate = gestureRecognizerDelegate
        self.rotateGestureRecognizer.delegate = gestureRecognizerDelegate
        ApplicationManager.sharedInstance.gotFloorData = drawFloor
        ApplicationManager.sharedInstance.currentUserPoint = drawCurrentUserPoint
    }

    func drawFloor (floor: Floor) {
        mapView.setFloor(currentFloor: floor)
        mapView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func drawCurrentUserPoint(currentUserPoint: CurrentUserLocation, beaconRangingData: [BeaconRangingPoint]) {
        mapView.setUserPoint(currentUserPoint: currentUserPoint, beaconRangingData: beaconRangingData)
        mapView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: mapView)
        if recognizer.view != nil {
            let offsetX = translation.x * CGFloat(cosf(Float(rotateView))) - translation.y * CGFloat(sinf(Float(rotateView)))
            let offsetY = translation.x * CGFloat(sinf(Float(rotateView))) + translation.y * CGFloat(cosf(Float(rotateView)))
            mapView.center = CGPoint(x:mapView.center.x + offsetX * scaleView,
                                     y:mapView.center.y + offsetY * scaleView)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: mapView)
    }

    @IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.view != nil {
            setAnchor(point: recognizer.location(in: mapView))
            mapView.transform = mapView.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
            scaleView = recognizer.scale * scaleView
            recognizer.scale = 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.view != nil {
            setAnchor(point: recognizer.location(in: mapView))
            mapView.transform = mapView.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
            rotateView = rotateView + recognizer.rotation
            recognizer.rotation = 0
        }
    }

    private func setAnchor(point : CGPoint) {
        let anchor = CGPoint(x: point.x / mapView.bounds.width, y: point.y / mapView.bounds.height)
        mapView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: anchor.x, y: anchor.y)
        let translationX = (mapView.bounds.width * (anchor.x - anchorPoint.x)) * scaleView
        let translationY = (mapView.bounds.height * (anchor.y - anchorPoint.y)) * scaleView
        let offsetX = translationX * CGFloat(cosf(Float(rotateView))) - translationY * CGFloat(sinf(Float(rotateView)))
        let offsetY = translationX * CGFloat(sinf(Float(rotateView))) + translationY * CGFloat(cosf(Float(rotateView)))
        mapView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: mapView.layer.position.x + offsetX,
                                         y: mapView.layer.position.y + offsetY)
        anchorPoint = anchor
    }

    private func showAlert(title: String, message: String?, style: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
        let tryAgainAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Try again", style: .default) {
            alertAction in
            ApplicationManager.sharedInstance.onApplicationStart()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(tryAgainAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func onOrientationChanged() {
        self.mapView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

also code of mapView:

```
import UIKit
```

class MapView: UIView {

```
private var floor = Floor(walls: [], doors: [], beacons: [])
private let wallColor = UIColor.black
private let doorColor = UIColor.red
private let triangleColor = UIColor.red
private let perpendicularColor = UIColor.darkGray
private let doorLength = 3.0
private let beaconColor = UIColor.green
private let beaconNoActiveColor = UIColor(red: 20/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 53.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
private let beaconFrameColor = UIColor.brown
private let lineWidthBeaconFrame:CGFloat = 0.25
private let beaconRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
private let userColor = UIColor.blue
private let userFrameColor = UIColor.brown
private let lineWidthUserFrame:CGFloat = 0.25
private let userRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
private let distanceBeaconColor = UIColor.clear
private let distanceBeaconFrameColor = UIColor.green
private let lineWidthOfDistanceFrame: CGFloat = 0.5
private let userRawRadius: CGFloat = 3.0
private let userRawColor = UIColor.darkGray
private let userRawFrameColor = UIColor.lightGray
private let lineWidthOfuserRawFrame: CGFloat = 0.8

private var beaconText: NSString = ""
private let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
private let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 5)!


private var currentUserLocation = CurrentUserLocation()
private var beaconRangingData: [BeaconRangingPoint] = []

func setFloor (currentFloor: Floor) {
    floor = currentFloor
}
func setUserPoint(currentUserPoint: CurrentUserLocation, beaconRangingData: [BeaconRangingPoint]) {
    self.currentUserLocation = currentUserPoint
    self.beaconRangingData = beaconRangingData
}
func dropPin(location: CGPoint) {
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let frameToDraw = CoordinatesConverter(boundsWidth: bounds.width, boundsHeight: bounds.height, paddingX: 5, paddingY: 5)
    let mapWithScaleCoordinaates =  frameToDraw.getSuitableCoordinates(floor: floor, currentUserLocation: currentUserLocation, beaconRangingData: beaconRangingData)
    let lines = mapWithScaleCoordinaates.lines
    let circles = mapWithScaleCoordinaates.circles

    drawLines(lines: lines)
    drawCircles(circles: circles)
 }

private func drawLines(lines :[Line]) {
    let wallPath = UIBezierPath()
    let doorPath = UIBezierPath()
    let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
    let perpendicularPath = UIBezierPath()

    for line in lines {
        if line.type == .wall {
            wallPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.x1, y: line.y1))
            wallPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line.x2, y: line.y2))
            wallColor.setStroke()
            wallPath.stroke()
        }
        if line.type == .door {
            doorPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.x1, y: line.y1))
            doorPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line.x2, y: line.y2))
            doorPath.lineWidth = CGFloat(doorLength)
            doorColor.setStroke()
            doorPath.stroke()
        }
        if line.type == .triangle {
            trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.x1, y: line.y1))
            trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line.x2, y: line.y2))
            triangleColor.setStroke()
            trianglePath.stroke()
        }
        if line.type == .perpendicular {
            perpendicularPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.x1, y: line.y1))
            perpendicularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line.x2, y: line.y2))
            perpendicularColor.setStroke()
            perpendicularPath.stroke()
        }
    }
}

private func drawCircles(circles: [Circle]) {
    let layerViews = layer.sublayers
    if layerViews != nil {
        for view in layerViews! {
            if type(of: view) === CAShapeLayer.self {
                view.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    for circle in circles {

        if type(of: circle) === BeaconCircle.self  {
            if (circle as! BeaconCircle).correctedDistance  == 0 {
                infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: beaconRadius, color: beaconNoActiveColor.cgColor, frameColor: beaconFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthBeaconFrame)
                drawBeaconText(circle: circle as! BeaconCircle)
            } else {
                infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: beaconRadius, color: beaconColor.cgColor, frameColor: beaconFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthBeaconFrame)
                drawBeaconText(circle: circle as! BeaconCircle)
            }

            if type(of: circle) === BeaconCircle.self && (circle as! BeaconCircle).correctedDistance != 0 {
                infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: CGFloat((circle as! BeaconCircle).correctedDistance), color: distanceBeaconColor.cgColor, frameColor: distanceBeaconFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthOfDistanceFrame)
              //   infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: CGFloat((circle as! BeaconCircle).notCorrectedDistance), color: UIColor.gray.cgColor, frameColor: distanceBeaconFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthOfDistanceFrame)
            }

        } else if type(of: circle) === UserCircle.self {
            infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: userRadius, color: userColor.cgColor, frameColor: userFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthUserFrame)
        } else if type (of: circle) === UserRawCircle.self {
            infoToDrawCircle(circle: circle, radius: userRawRadius, color: userRawColor.cgColor, frameColor: userRawFrameColor.cgColor, frameWidth: lineWidthOfuserRawFrame)
        } else {
            Logger.logMessage(message: "incorrect circle type", level: .error)
            break
        }
    }
}



private func drawBeaconText (circle: BeaconCircle) {
    let attributes: NSDictionary = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont
    ]
    let minor = circle.minor
    let correctDistance = Int(round(100 * circle.correctDistanceForText) / 100)
    let notCorrectDistance = Int(round(100 * circle.notCorrectDistanceForText) / 100)
    beaconText = "m: \(minor), cd: \(correctDistance), nd: \(notCorrectDistance)" as NSString
    if circle.x > Int((bounds.width - 50)) {
        beaconText.draw(at: CGPoint(x: circle.x - 70, y: circle.y + 5), withAttributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
    } else if circle.x < 20 {
        beaconText.draw(at: CGPoint(x: circle.x + 5, y: circle.y + 5), withAttributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
    } else {
         beaconText.draw(at: CGPoint(x: circle.x + 6, y: circle.y + 5), withAttributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
    }
}

private func infoToDrawCircle (circle: Circle, radius: CGFloat, color: CGColor, frameColor: CGColor, frameWidth: CGFloat) {
    let center = CGPoint(x: circle.x, y: circle.y)
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = frameWidth
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = frameColor
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you conform your `MapViewController` to the `MKMapViewDelegate`. In this way you can add annotations (also animated) to the map and you won't have to worry about them anymore since it's all handled by the map delegate.

You can use:

`self.map.showAnnotations(pins, animated: true)`

where `pins` is an array of `MKAnnotation`. [Here is the link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452309-showannotations) to the documentation for the method.

Cheers